# CSV in PHP. Lines not on one line

Tags: php, csv

EDIT: Fixed, I had to remove all spaces I had (before the commas in the code below) and use trim

I'm trying to generate a CSV file using PHP. However the file splits into lines on its own. It looks fine in View Source, but excel/notepad show lines randomly broken up.

Here is my code :

```
// Echo Code Here
$string = '"REF1" , "FIRSTCLASS" ,"P" ,"1" ,"' . $orderref . '" ,"' . $fullname . '" ,"' . $add1 . '" ,"' . $add2 . '" ,"" ,"' . $postcode . '" ,"' . $city . '" ,"' . $country . '" ,"' . $fullname . '" ,"' . $telephone . '" ,"' . $email . '" ,"1" ,"1.0 kg"' . "\n";
echo $string;
```

Any help would be great, this is my first time working with CSV in PHP.

Comment: Do any of those variables you're inserting have linebreaks in them? Try doing `trim($orderref)`, `trim($fullname)`, etc... If the split occurs in the MIDDLE of one of those inserted variables, you'll have to manually remove the bad characters.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Thank you Marc, that was the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Windows, you should use Windows-style line endings: `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.

Comment: Using the [PHP_EOL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) constant may help with portability if the code will end up used on different platforms. "The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2"

Answer (score 0):

There is PHP function forwriting CSV into file:

PHP "fputcsv" function
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php